# Adding a new virtual NIC to Linux virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-fusion

I'm facing a strange problem with a Linux Machine imported in VMWare Fusion from a OVA Virtual Box file. After importing the only NIC is lo.
So I removed the Network Adapter and add a new one. But I cannot connect to the network because the new NIC is not present. 
The OVA file come from a virtual software appliance for pentest exerices. It's a debian 6 distro. 
Update: issuing a ifconfig -a command there is also a ens33 iterface. What does it means?

Comment: Rebooting usually will detect new hardware, but if you've got some custom VM it could be configured differently.  Can you edit your question to include the OVA details, i.e. your own, something downloaded, linux distro, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ens33` is the device name.

As root (use `su -` followed by the root password OR `sudo -i` followed by the user's password) you can edit `/etc/network/interfaces`

It should look like this for a static address -

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Or like this for a DHCP address -

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens33
iface ens33 inet dhcp
```

If you are using a static address, put the IP of a reachable DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf` like so - If you are using DHCP then it should get set correctly automatically.

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

You can also try to just get a DHCP lease with

`dhclient -v ens33`